# Did the Romans have sarcasm?

Tags: classical-latin

Do we have any evidence of the use of sarcasm to create humor/insults in Latin - that is, intentional stress changes of words in order to imply falsehood of the statement being made?

Comment: Very closely related: [Is there a way to make a sentence ironic in Latin?](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/455/12)  Could you explain what you'd like to know that isn't covered there?

Comment: @Nathaniel Huh. Should I delete the question or just let it stand?

Comment: It's a good question, so we can close it as a duplicate of the one I've linked.  If you later think of a way to differentiate this one from that one, we can always reopen it.